# Low or high side switching for ZVS Mazzilli induction circuit?

Tags: mosfet, induction, zvs

I'm trying to teach myself electrical engineering as a hobby and have been studying zero voltage switching induction heating circuits. I'm learning about electronics and designing a circuit as I go along.

Let's say I have a ZVS Mazzilli flyback driver (not even sure exactly what to call this, there are many names out there like Royer etc.) like this, operating on a 12V 8A power supply:

[image: Text]

I want to switch this circuit on with an IC but I'm not sure if it would be better to do high or low side switching with a MOSFET.

1. Would high or low side switching be better? (High side with a P-channel MOSFET and a driver? Or would low side with an N-channel be preferred? And why? I want to learn more about the considerations in a high frequency circuit like this, on a basic electronics level.)
2. Are there any considerations for the ground plane and return paths? Considering the IC and additional components? Can everything share a common ground plane or pour on a PCB?

Comment: This is just a fancy/teach/experiment circuit. Nothing serious that can last and that has protection features, so it makes no sense to use expensive gate drivers, multilayer PCB,...

Comment: Thanks for replying! I understand what you're saying, I'm just learning and experimenting. My question still stands though, I'm just trying to understand more about MOSFETs, ground return paths and basic electronics and PCB design in general.

Comment: N-channel MOSFET will have lower Rds(on) resistance compared to P-channel in general. Also, understanding what is going on "inside" this "simple" circuit is not an easy job. But it seems that Peter Baxandall was first who used this circuit http://sophia-elektronica.com/0344_001_Baxandal.pdf (fig. 5)